# Update value after render

Tags: reactjs

I am doing this:

```
const changePrice = (event) => {
  let {value} = event.target;
  priceBook = JSON.parse(value).price
}

return (
  <div className="container">
    <select onChange={changePrice}>
        {planes.map((book, index) => {
          return <option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(book)}>{book.pages}</option>
        })}
    </select>
    <span>Price {priceBook} </span>
  </div>
);
```

And it loads the selector values ​​well, but when I change the value I should update the price value in the view, which does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a change to the state to trigger a component render. You can do this as answered by @Dupocas or try to use a setState in a class component, like this:

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    <select
      onChange={(event) => {
        let { value } = event.target;
        this.setState({
          priceBook: JSON.parse(value).price || 0
        })
      }}
    >
        {planes.map((book, index) => {
          return <option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(book)}>{book.pages}</option>
        })}
    </select>
    <span>Price { this.state.priceBook } </span>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

To implement stateful logic inside function based components use `hooks`:

```
const [priceBook, setPriceBook] = useState('such empty')
const changePrice = (event) => {
    let {value} = event.target;
    const priceBook = JSON.parse(value).price
    setPriceBook(pricebook)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <select onChange={changePrice}>
          {planes.map((book, index) => {
            return <option key={index} value={book.price}>{book.pages}</option>
          })}
      </select>
      <span>Price {priceBook} </span>
    </div>
  );
```